Missing tamagui config
Context
I created a new tamagui project using their template (which included expo-router and some other libs).
It worked great until, I started encountering an issue randomly yesterday when I tried running the project on the android simulator. Up till that point I had not encountered any issues.
Problem
I'm getting the following error when running yarn android, the simulator is showing a "Rendor Error"

Missing tamagui config, you either have a duplicate config,
or haven't set it up. Be sure createTamagui is called before
rendering. Also, make sure all of your tamagui dependencies
are on the same version ('tamagui', '@tamagui/package-name', etc.)
not just in your package.json, but in your lockfile.

What I've done

The tamagui.config.ts is set at the root directory of the project and it exports the config file
I'm importing the config to app/Provider.tsx and I'm passing the config to the <TamaguiProvider config={config} ...
I've logged the config in the file mentioned previously and it's properly set.
The libraries are all set at the same version 1.120.0 (in package.json + yarn.lock file, only thing I've noticed is that the @tamagui/core library is set to 1.120.2)
I've rm -rf node_modules android + yarn cache clean and reinstalled everything without success.

Question
How do I resolve the error mentioned previously? Why was it working the other day and all of a sudden it no longer works?
Code
note: i'm aware that I'm exporting the config twice, one as a named export and the other as default. I've played around with both and it doesn't change anything.
// tamagui.config.ts

import { createTamagui } from "tamagui";
import { config as defaultConfig } from "@tamagui/config/v3";

export type Conf = typeof config;

declare module "tamagui" {
  interface TamaguiCustomConfig extends Conf {}
}

const colors = {
  // colors here and used in createTamagui config
};

const config = createTamagui({
  // Stuff here
});

export type TamaguiConfig = typeof config;
export default config;

// app/Provider.tsx

import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { TamaguiProvider, type TamaguiProviderProps } from "tamagui";
import { ToastProvider, ToastViewport } from "@tamagui/toast";
import { CurrentToast } from "./CurrentToast";
import config from "../tamagui.config";
import { ParentHeightProvider } from "./providers/ParentHeightContext";

export function Provider({
  children,
  ...rest
}: Omit<TamaguiProviderProps, "config">) {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <TamaguiProvider
      config={config}
      defaultTheme={colorScheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}
      {...rest}
    >
      <ParentHeightProvider>
        <ToastProvider
          swipeDirection="horizontal"
          duration={6000}
          native={
            [
              /* uncomment the next line to do native toasts on mobile. NOTE: it'll require you making a dev build and won't work with Expo Go */
              // 'mobile'
            ]
          }
        >
          {children}
          <CurrentToast />
          <ToastViewport top="$8" left={0} right={0} />
        </ToastProvider>
      </ParentHeightProvider>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  );
}

